# Two two-by-two positive matrices both have positive entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive linear operators on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

How can we see that the matrices of both $A$ and $B$ have only non-negative entries in some basis?

What is special about $\mathbb{C}^2$ that does not generalize to higher dimensions?

Comment: The statement is not true as it stands. E.g. **No** change of basis would turn the identity matrix $I_2$ into an entrywise positive matrix. It always has two off-diagonal zero entries. Also, you may want to clarify whether you are talking about *orthonormal* bases or just any basis.

Comment: Excuse me, I'll edit this to non-negative entries.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, suppose $\{u,v\}$ is an orthonormal eigenbasis of $A$ (it exists because $A$ is positive). Now consider $\{u,v\}$ or $\{u,-v\}$.